# How do you plot a graph so x variable and y variable is against each other?

Tags: r, plot, graph, statistics

I'm very new to R and I just don't know how to place the variables so they are against each other. I'm a new student in data science major.

I have a code as follows:

```
plot(x=H_L$fl, y=H_L$age, xlim= c(0,500), ylim=c(0,15), xlab = "Age(yrs)", ylab = "Fork Length(mm)", main="Plot 4: Symbol & Color by Era")
```

And the prompt asks,

Create a plot of “Age (yrs)” (y variable) versus “Fork Length (mm)” (x variable) with the
following specifications:

• Limit of x axis is (0,500)
• Limit of y axis is (0,15)
• Title of graph is “Plot 4: Symbol & Color by Era”
• X axis label is “Age (yrs)”
• Y axis label is “Fork Length (mm)”
• Set pch equal to pchs era values
• Set col equal to cols era values

I'm here to learn :) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the help for `?plot()` or `?par()`

Comment: Hi there. Yes, I have. The ?plot() function just tells you basic plotting, but not in sense that x,y variables are against each other. I've researching on the web for awhile and I just can't find the solution to it.

Comment: Try searching something along the lines of "base R plot" for example there are loads of tutorials for example totally at random: https://intro2r.com/simple-base-r-plots.html

Comment: I haven't found the answer yet but, I'll definitely check it out. The website you provided seems very very useful - not just for this assignment, but in studying for futures as well. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know what it means when you ask for "place the variables so they are against each other". You are plotting "fl" versus "age". How is that not plotting "against"?

Comment: Oh my god. You are definitely correct. I've been sitting here I think the past 10 hours or so.. so my brain probably had been melted. I have the following codes. plot(x=H_L$fl, y=H_L$age, xlim= c(0,500), ylim=c(0,15), xlab = "Age(yrs)", ylab = "Fork Length(mm)", main="Plot 4: Symbol & Color by Era", pch=ifelse(H_L$era == "1977-80", pchs[1], pchs[2]), 
     col=ifelse(H_L$era == "1977-80", cols[1], cols[2])) Thanks for helping out.